# Using pyodbc to run sql query but get Error: "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Tags: sql-server, aws-lambda, odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc

I have this running in an aws lambda function to run sql queries in a MSSQL database. The pyodbc connection string i'm using is:

```
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    server="SERVER NAME",
    database="DATABASE NAME",
    user=sql_username,
    password=sql_password,
    port=1433,
    driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    )
```

Which gives me error:

`[ERROR] InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

I have the relevant drivers. In file `odbc.ini`:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description = My ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Trace = No
```

In file `odbcinst.ini`:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

And that is the correct path to the driver.

I have noticed there is a "ODBCDataSources" folder that came along with the other odbc files but the folder is empty. Should there be something in here?

Or is there something else that would be causing the error?

Comment: Does the file `/opt/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1` exist? The most current ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server version is 17.9.1.1.

Comment: You can use the [odbcinst](https://github.com/gordthompson/odbcinst) module to verify that unixODBC is looking at the odbc*.ini files that you think it is.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for responding. yes the file exists. But i also tried with the most recent 18 driver and still receive the same error

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for responding. Do you mean is should drop that bit of code into my lambda to confirm where it is looking? I'm assuming i would need to add the files needed for it use odbcinst to the lambda if so? Sorry if the answer to this is obvious!